# Change order (weight) of blocks before page load programatically

Tags: blocks

Is there a way to change order of blocks before page load (according to current node id for expample)? In hook_preprocess_page or something like that? I don't want to use any modules for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [hook_block_list_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_list_alter/7) to achieve this. Be aware that the `$block->weight` attribute won't be affected at this point in the proceedings, but there are solutions in the comments to this problem.

Comment: It means that order of blocks in `hook_block_list_alter(&$blocks)` function can be changed simply by resorting blocks in `&$blocks` array, right? Thx.